# my server program can't print after connecting to client

Tags: java

I am running a project of java on my mac with eclipse
before the server being able to connect to client it prints normally.
However, after I run my client program and successfully connect to my server ,my server can't print anything at all.(But i assume that my server can still working since it can do "DataOutputStream"(line:25,26)but the client receive it wrongly)
this is my server:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int producta=10;
        int productb=8;
        try{
            System.out.println("java Server > A:10 , B:8 , <12345>");
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(12345);
            Socket connectionSock = serverSock.accept( );
            BufferedReader clientInput = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connectionSock.getInputStream( )));
            DataOutputStream clientOutput = new DataOutputStream( connectionSock.getOutputStream( ));
            System.out.println("java Server > Connection made, waiting for client " + "to send their ptoduct number.");
            System.out.println("test");
            clientOutput.write(producta);
            clientOutput.write(productb);
            int clientnum1= clientInput.read();//read client productA
            producta-=clientnum1;
            int clientnum2=clientInput.read();//read client product B
            productb-=clientnum2;
            clientOutput.writeInt(producta);
            clientOutput.writeInt(productb);
            
            clientOutput.close( ); 
            clientInput.close( ); 
            connectionSock.close( ); 
            serverSock.close( );
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("java Server > Socket連線有問題");
        }
    }
}
```

this is my client:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=0;
        int b=0;
        int clientnum=0;
        try{        
            
            String hostname = "localhost"; 
            int port = 12345;
            System.out.println("java client > Connecting to server on port " + port); 
            System.out.println("Resouce requirement:<A:0 , B:0>");
            System.out.print("java client > number a:");
            a=scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("java client > number b:");
            b=scan.nextInt();
            Socket connectionSock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
            BufferedReader serverInput=null;
            DataOutputStream serverOutput=null;
            if(connectionSock!=null){
                clientnum++;
                serverInput = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(connectionSock.getInputStream( )));
                serverOutput = new DataOutputStream( connectionSock.getOutputStream( ));
                System.out.println("java client > Connection made, sending number.<A:"+a+",B:"+b+">"); 
                int serverA=serverInput.read();//read the server prodduct b number
                System.out.println(serverA);
                int serverB=serverInput.read();//read the server product a number
                serverOutput.write(a);
                serverOutput.write(b);
                serverA=serverInput.read();
                serverB=serverInput.read();
                System.out.println(serverA);
                System.out.println(serverB);            
            }//end if
            else{
                System.out.println("java client > [client"+clientnum+"]:resource insufficient!Error");
            }//end else
            System.out.println("java client > Waiting for reply."); 
            serverOutput.close( ); 
            serverInput.close( ); 
            connectionSock.close( );
        }//end try
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage( )); 
            System.out.println("client's connecting probleming");
        }//end catch
    }//end main
}//end class
```

This is the result of the running (the server line:24,25didn't print out)

How can i print out the server line 24,25?

[image]

Comment: I dont get it. What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: how can i print out the server line 24,25?(i just add a screenshot of my running result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `writeInt()` method of `DataOutputStream` at server side

**Server side**

```
   DataInputStream clientInput = new DataInputStream( connectionSock.getInputStream( ));
   DataOutputStream clientOutput = new DataOutputStream( connectionSock.getOutputStream( ));
   System.out.println("java Server > Connection made, waiting for client " + "to send their ptoduct number.");
   System.out.println("test");

   clientOutput.writeInt(producta); //writeInt() not write()
   clientOutput.writeInt(productb);
```

At **client side** dont use `BufferedReader`  for reading integers from server. Simply read these integers using `readInt()` method of `DataInputStream`

```
    clientnum++;
    serverInput = new DataInputStream(connectionSock.getInputStream());
    serverOutput = new DataOutputStream(connectionSock.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("java client > Connection made, sending number.<A:" + a + ",B:" + b + ">");
    int serverA = serverInput.readInt();// read the server prodduct a number
    System.out.println("product A number from server > " + serverA);                                    

    int serverB = serverInput.readInt();// read the server product b
    System.out.println("product A number from server > " + serverB);
```

Comment: yes! I think i did work in some part since i actually got the  a more reasonable result when the client run!

Comment: the results was like                                                                             "java client > Connecting to server on port 12345       
java client >Resouce requirement:<A:0 , B:0>
java client > number a:3
java client > number b:1
java client > Connection made, sending number.<A:3,B:1>
10
10
8
java client > Waiting for reply.
"

Comment: but still the "System.out.println" in the server part still didn't printout...(is there any to do with eclipse ?or mac)

Comment: @洪瑋襄 Its because you have no `System.out.println()` statement after line 29 at server side

Comment: thank a lots ! with your help  i finally found the problem!